# Start Dagster Schedule automatically

Tags: python-3.x, dagster

Hi i am learning dagster and i want help with starting schedule
I am able to add and start schedule in dagit but i want to start schedule automatically instead of turn on every schedule from dagit.

#Here is my code

```
@solid()
def test(context):
   context.log.info("test")
  
@pipeline()
def testPipeline():
    test()

@schedule(
    cron_schedule="* * * * *", pipeline_name="testPipeline", execution_timezone="Asia/Kolkata"
)
def scheduleTest():
    return {}

@repository()
def testRepo():
    return [testPipeline, scheduleTest]
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a very same question on dagster slack so I'm forwarding Daniel Gibson's answer which might help.

- since 0.14.0 release, it will be possible to create already enabled schedule (will be released in a week).
- also, there's a `dagster schedule start --start-all` command line command, calling that any time you add a schedule would be one workaround

Answer (score 2):

There's a `startSchedule` mutation in the [Dagster GraphQL API](https://docs.dagster.io/concepts/dagit/graphql#graphql-api), which has a Python client. I'm not sure how to call it to start your specific schedule, but I think this route is a good way to go.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://docs.dagster.io/concepts/partitions-schedules-sensors/schedules#running-the-scheduler) you can try this:

```py
my_running_schedule = ScheduleDefinition(
    job=my_job, cron_schedule="0 9 * * *", default_status=DefaultScheduleStatus.RUNNING
)
```